# Using WCF ClientBase from Multiple threads

Tags: wcf, concurrency, http-authentication

I have WCF interface contract which is behind basic HTTP authentication. This serice have mostly stream methods for large file transfers (streaming). What i want is call one ClientBase instance call from multiple threads.

But when i do that, only one file is transfered at the time. Is WCF serializing requests and locking channel?

What is the best strategy for client creation for WCF service in .NET 4.5 for concurrent environment?